# What is the LUMO and HOMO in and O2 diatomic

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

In the molecular orbital (MO) diagram for the $O_2$ diatomic, the $2π_g^*$ contains two unpaired electrons. This is certainly the HOMO, as it is the highest molecular orbital with electrons. My question is, is the LUMO of this molecule the $6σ_u^*$ (which is definitely unoccupied)? or is the LUMO the $2π_g^*$?

On the one hand, it feels very weird to have both the LUMO and the HOMO be the same orbital, but it also feels like you should be removing electrons from the HOMO, and adding them to the LUMO, but you both add and remove electrons to the  $2π_g^*$.

In other words, what happens to the LUMO, when an orbital is partially filled.

Comment: In the typical way these terms are used, the LUMO can't be the same as the HOMO. Since each of the pi spatial orbitals already have one electron, they are not unoccupied, so they can't be the LUMO. In the sense of singly occupied spin orbitals, you could say that these pi spin orbitals are the LUMO, but its fairly nonstandard to refer to spin orbitals when discussing HOMO/LUMO.